# Show a name instaed of id when using raw_id_fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i'm using raw_id_field in Django admin models , i want to display a Serial number or any thing rather than id in the admin model.

is there any way to do it??

update:

by specifying the primary key , then the primary key will appear.

Comment: have you found any solution to display other value than the id

Comment: yes , in the admin page put this                                 raw_id_fields = ("name of FK field")

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to have your model files but from a quick guess.

in your models.py:

```
class YourModelname(models.Model):
    code_postal = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    pays = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):  #you need to add this to show the name of the content
        return unicode(self.code_postal)
```

Here it will show me the postal code.

if you want to list more information go in your admin.py

```
class YourModelname(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('code_postal ', 'ville ', '...', 'pays')


admin.site.register(Clients, YourModelname)
```

From what I have I can only guess it is this if you can edit more information about the models.py and admin.py we could help you faster next time.

Comment: do you have a link to yours?

Comment: internal project, what is the point with a "link" that you want ?

Comment: a link to your own question on stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400564/django-admin-override-dropdown-with-selection-from-popup-window/24400866#24400866