# Django admin, override dropdown with selection from popup window

Tags: django, django-admin

In a one-to-many relationship, how can I override the drop-down menu in the change-form to be able to select value from popup window, specially when dropdown could hold a pretty long list which may slowdown the page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer:

> raw_id_fields is a list of fields you would like to change into an
>   Input widget for either a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField:
>
> class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>       raw_id_fields = ("newspaper",)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

The question now is how can I display a user friendly value instead of the Id returned from the popup.